# JSON UTC to Web3 provider

Tags: dapps, dapp-development

We are using @truffle/hdwallet-provider [1] to sign transactions when deploying smart contracts on Besu. All the provided examples left the private key or the mnemonic in plain text in the truffle config file. I would like to use a JSON UTC file.

What is the best way to solve that?

[1] https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is about security, a general approach is by using package [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) in order to load environment variables and avoid hardcoding secret keys or mnemonics in your code.

You just need to create a file like this in your root directory:

```
.env
```

In this file you can add all the passwords you need, for instance:

```
INFURA_APP_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Finally, you can add the below code in your Truffle config:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const INFURA_APP_KEY = process.env.INFURA_APP_KEY;
```

By the way, if you are using Github or similar version controlling, never forget to add this `.env` file in the `.gitignore` one to avoid versioning your sensitive information in a repository.